# Automatically go to date of current day

Tags: php, time

I have a problem that I can not find a solution for. I made a timetable. **Now I want to automatically go to the current day's data.**

Right now when you see the timetable it initially shows Monday, instead I would like it to show the current day.

How can I tackle this easily?

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$dagvanweek = $arraydag[date("w")];

$dag = $_GET['dag'];

if ($dag!="maandag" && $dag!="dinsdag" && $dag!="woensdag" && $dag!="donderdag" && $dag!="vrijdag" && $dag!="zaterdag" && $dag!="zondag")


$huidigedag = date("l");
$arraydag = array(
    "zondag",
    "maandag",
    "dinsdag",
    "woensdag",
    "donderdag",
    "vrijdag",
    "zaterdag"
    );
 $huidigedag = $arraydag[date("w")];


$header = "<hr />

Kies een dag: 
<a href='?dag=maandag'>Maandag</a> |
<a href='?dag=dinsdag'>Dinsdag</a> |
<a href='?dag=woensdag'>Woensdag</a> |
<a href='?dag=donderdag>Donderdag</a> |
<a href='?dag=vrijdag'>Vrijdag</a> |
<a href='?dag=zaterdag'>Zaterdag</a> |
<a href='?dag=zondag'>Zondag</a> 

<br />";



$get = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS num FROM event_rooster WHERE dag='$huidigedag' AND `naam`!=''");  
if($get->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'Geen rijen';
}
else
{
    echo "$header <p><table align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width='400' border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3'>
    <tr>
    <th>Naam</td>
    <th>Evenement</td>
    <th>Tijd</td>
    </tr>";

    $q1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM event_rooster WHERE `dag`='$dag' AND `naam`!='' ORDER BY `id` ASC ");
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1))
    {

 }




        echo "<tr>
        <td>".stripslashes($r['event'])."</td>
        <td>".stripslashes($r['omschrijving'])."</td>
        <td>".stripslashes($r['tijd'])."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

**Sorry, it is written in dutch.**

```
Maandag = Monday
Dinsdag = Tuesday
Woensdag = Wednesday
Donderdag = Thursday
Vrijdag = Friday
Zaterdag = Saturday
Zondag = Sunday
```

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are asking when you say "When you go to the first day of the week (Monday), it should go to the current day". Is Monday the first day that shows and you want to instead go to the current day?

Comment: dag in the query to **default** to today ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not clear what you want but for a guess:

```
$dag = $_GET['dag'];

if(empty($dag)){
    $dag=date("l"); //assumes you set location properly and day name is in dutch
}
```